# Farseer - Difference between Position, GetLocalVector, and GetWorldVector

Tags: c#, physics, box2d, physics-engine, farseer-physics-engine

I have used Box2D extensively, and am used to just calling `body.GetPosition()`. But Farseer does not have this. Instead it has a property `Position`, as well as methods `GetLocalVector` and `GetWorldVector`. Farseer seemingly has a complete lack of documentation, and I have been unable to figure out what the difference is.

Also, though I feel a bit dumb about it, I don't really get what `GetWorldVector` means as opposed to `GetLocalVector`. They take a `localVector` and a `worldVector` as their respective arguments, but what does that mean? What is the difference between local and world vectors?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so obviously `Position` is simply the position of the `Body` in the world.

In order to fully explain `GetLocalVector` and `GetWorldVector`, I will also explain the `GetLocalPoint` and `GetWorldPoint` methods.

As you say, Farseer's documentation is not great. My advice is to build it from source within your own Solution, so you can easily investigate what's going on - and even tweak it to suit your needs.

Each `Body` in Farseer has a **transform** (`_xf`) made up of a **position** (`_xf.p`) and a **rotation** (`_xf.q`).

Knowing this, we can look at the four methods in question:

```
// GetLocalVector
return MathUtils.MulT(_xf.q, worldVector);

// GetLocalPoint
return MathUtils.MulT(ref _xf, worldPoint);

// GetWorldVector
return MathUtils.Mul(_xf.q, localVector);

// GetWorldPoint
return MathUtils.Mul(ref _xf, ref localPoint);
```

As you may know, when you multiply a point by a transformation matrix you are transforming it from one space into another. The transformation in this case transforms from the the local space of the body (where you specify your `Fixture`s, where `Vector2.Zero` is the origin of the body) into world space. (The **`World`** variants.)

Because the matrices in these cases are orthogonal, multiplying by the transpose (`MulT`) is the same as multiplying by the inverse. And, as you might expect, multiplying by the inverse performs the transform in the opposite direction (in this case: from world space into local space). (The **`Local`** variants.)

The variants (**`Vector`**) that only use the rotation (`_xf.q`) are for use with relative positions, and directions, where including an absolute offset in the transformation does not make sense.

**If that explanation went over your head, let me try some examples:**

Say your body has some kind of turret on it for firing weapons, offset from the body's origin. You would use `GetWorldPoint(muzzlePosition)` when you fire the weapon to figure out where in the world the projectile should be spawned. You would use `GetWorldVector(muzzleVelocity)` to set the velocity of the fired projectile.

Say your body is clickable. You would use `GetLocalPoint(worldMousePosition)` to find out the position on the body that was clicked. (Transforming the mouse position into world space is left as an exercise.)

Say you have many versions of the sprite that represents your body - each lit from a different direction. You would use the output of `GetLocalVector(sunlightDirection)` to select an appropriate sprite.